# create a custom hover for non siblings elements with tailwind

Tags: html, css, hover, tailwind-css

This is my html code and I want to change the color of the mouse div when the ul div is hovered.

I tried to do it from the config file but it does not work.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        wiggle: {
          '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
        }
      },
      '@layer utilities': {
        '.group-hover\\:hover-class:hover .target-class': {
          /* Your hover styles go here */
          backgroundColor: '#ffcc00', 
          color: '#333', 
        }
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This is my html code. I tried to do the peer and the group technique but nothing works.

```html
<div id="mouse" class="fixed h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-white transition-all duration-[20ms] mix-blend-difference z-[100] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] pointer-events-none" ></div>
<nav class="relative px-4 py-8  flex justify-between items-center bg-transparent animate__animated animate__fadeInDown z-50">
  <ul class=" hidden  absolute top-1/2  right-36 z-[51] transform -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 lg:flex lg:mx-auto lg:items-center lg:w-auto lg:space-x-6" id="uall">
    <li><a class="text-sm cursor-none text-white hover:text-white font-black"  href="#">Home</a></li>   
    <li><a class="text-sm cursor-none text-white hover:text-[#fdcb6e] font-black" href="#">Pricing</a></li> 
    <li><a class="text-sm cursor-none text-white hover:text-[#fdcb6e] font-black " href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Could you clarify which element is the "ul div" please?